# Planing a laminated curve

Tags: thickness-planer

Preface, I have not worked with a planer before.

I have a curved piece of wood which was created by laminating three 1/4" oak boards over a form.  The curve looks good but I would like to clean up the edge.  I can do this with a sander of course, but was wondering if I could pass it through a thickness planer.  Basically place the piece on its side (its about 3" wide) and pass it through.

Is this "safe" to do on a planer? Should I pass the form through too to provide support?

Comment: How long is the piece and what is the approx radius of the curves?

Comment: I see from the Comment below that you went with passing it over your jointer, that's what I would have recommended if you had a jointer. As a fan of hand tools I would also plug doing this with a hand plane, this sort of thing is very easily done with one of those with a bit of tweaking to get a light, tearout-free cut regardless of grain direction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends the exact profile of the curve (how "thick" it looks to the planer), but I would hazard that a thickness planer is not a safe option for this. Due to the irregular surface that will be given both to the rollers and the cutting head, I would be concerned that the piece tips over unexpectedly while inside (probably at the beginning, before the second roller engages).

Bracing the curved piece in a form that is the same height as the width of the piece will alleviate these concerns.

However, due to large amounts of glue in the laminated wood I would worry about marring the planer knives. Matthias over at woodgears.ca documented this effect from [running plywood on his jointer](https://woodgears.ca/jointer/plywood.html). Commercial plywood is probably rougher on the knives than your laminated oak (with only 2 glue lines), but together with the risk of going through the planer I wouldn't try that.

Comment: Thank you that is the expected answer sadly. I guess its clamp and sand time yay!

Comment: Good advice above. If you had access to a handheld power plane and a reasonably steady hand, you could knock off the high spots. You'll find that some people will pass a curved piece through a tablesaw, but that's pretty high risk and bothersome, given that you'd have to attach it to a sled of some description to straighten the fence edge to cut the first edge.

Comment: Actually I took a shot at running it through the jointer and that did a decent job.

Comment: Since you are holding the wood and passing it through the jointer, there is no risk like with a thickness planer. However, I would still worry about nicking the knives - run a piece of pine through the jointer now and verify that there are no "ridges" on the jointed surface.

Comment: It's best not to extrapolate too much from that example on Woodgears. People joint and thickness glued-up boards all the time without any damage to their knives or cutter heads. The glue used on commercial plywood is the major factor there (big big issue with particleboard/chipboard too, which has even more of the same glue in the core and is unbelievably abrasive).